# What is the best way to implement changing the color of a point based on the value for a shapefile?

Tags: python, dataframe, geopandas

I have a dataframe containing data and lat lon values and I want to plot the data onto a shapefile.

The points should be colored based on the value of the data.

If data is less than 50 value should be green. If between 50 to 100 value should be yellow, 100 to 150 should be orange, 150 to 200 should be red, and greater than 200 should be purple.

Is there a simple pythonic way to do it?

Here is something I tried, but this is pretty slow:

```
for i in range(0,len(dailyAQI)):
    if dailyAQI['dailyAQI'].iloc[i] < 50:
        dailyAQI.loc[i,'colors']  = 'g'

    elif 50< dailyAQI['dailyAQI'].iloc[i] <= 100:
        dailyAQI.loc[i,'colors']  = 'y'

    elif 100 < dailyAQI['dailyAQI'].iloc[i] <= 150:
        dailyAQI.loc[i, 'colors'] = 'b'

    elif 150< dailyAQI['dailyAQI'].iloc[i]  <= 200:
        dailyAQI.loc[i, 'colors'] = 'r'

    elif dailyAQI['dailyAQI'].iloc[i] > 200:
        dailyAQI.loc[i, 'colors'] = 'k'
```

I also tried using np.where, but not sure how to make it use more than two statements.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems are you running into? There's definitely many ways to do it, some of them more pythonic than others

Comment: added some code to the description

Comment: Your code is a roundabout way of setting the `'colors'` columns of a dataframe to a single letter colour name - are you merely looking for a more efficient way of updating that column?

Comment: Not necessarily, I want to plot my values onto a shapefile and have the points on the plot be color coded, based on the rules above